# Azure Search: How to make a field globally unique

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm creating an `Azure Search` index and would like a field to be globally unique. Initially, I tried using the `id` field for this purpose, but it looks like certain characters are not allowed in the `id` field. Is it possible to define a field as globally unique at the time of index schema creation?

Answer (score 1):

> "key"- Unique identifier for documents within the index. Exactly one
> field must be chosen as the key field and it must be of type
> Edm.String.
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-what-is-an-index#attributes

If you encounter characters not being supported in Azure Search, have a look at base64 encoding your field using [field mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-field-mappings).